# enabling ipsec, ah and esp on CentOS with firewalld in place

Tags: centos, firewall, docker, firewalld, ipsec

On my CentOS I have firewalld running and my eth0 is in default zone. I use dockers for my services to communicate and in dockers I have enabled encryption. Docker creates an overlay network and uses IPSEC. But firewalld drops IPSEC connection. I found a link which has about 5-6 commands for IPSEC to work and if I play those commands, things work fine. 
These are listed on this link https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=56130

I am not clear how the default zone is where my nic eth0 is and I have to modify dmz zone. What is the use of masquerade and port 4500?

```
firewall-cmd --zone=dmz --permanent --add-rich-rule='rule protocol value="esp" accept'

firewall-cmd --zone=dmz --permanent --add-rich-rule='rule protocol value="ah" accept'

firewall-cmd --zone=dmz --permanent --add-port=500/udp 

firewall-cmd --zone=dmz --permanent --add-port=4500/udp 

firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service="ipsec"

firewall-cmd --zone=dmz --permanent --add-masquerade
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The masquerade rule tells the system to enable nat on outgoing connections, which is typical of networks using private internal addressing. It's a routing rule not technically related to ipsec specifically. 
The port 4500 is used for ipsec nat traversal when one or both sides are behind other routers and don't have their own routable ip addresses. 
Each nic belongs to a zone, zones are preconfigured with rules. internal, dmz and public are quite different from each other.